# How to create Conga composer email template that pulls information for not just Parent Object, but Task , Work Item etc or other child object?

Tags: email-template, merge-field, conga

I have created an e-mail template that pulls the fields from parent object.
But now I want to create Conga Composer e-mail template that pulls information for not just parent object, but Task, Work Item etc. (other child objects).
Any solution?

Comment: N.B. Conga as in dance line, not 'Congo' as in river

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate report or query for each child object. For example, if you want to show Tasks on an Object. First make a report type (if one doesn't already exist) which links your object to Task. With this you can choose the fields you want to report on. Then create the report itself and drag the fields into the report. Save it and note down the Report Id (in the URL starting with '0OO').

Once you've done this. Add the following to the Conga URL: &ReportId=[YourCustomName]0OO...

Then when you click the Conga button, you should see the table "YourCustomName" in Template Builder.

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your reply. Can u please elaborate this as i am very new to salesforce ,  thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, what have you done so far?

Comment: Hi , thanks Fred , thank you very much , following your instruction i have just completed the task.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Can you please mark my answer as best? Thanks.